# Exam class: Add "end of question" text to end of questions

Tags: exam

I have exams with questions with many parts, some parts are quite lengthy, so the full question is spread across several pages. To help the students navigate, I would like to put automatically some text e.g. *"This is the end of Question N"* after each question.

Comment: `\question` is a list item.  These have no end as such but rather are ended by either a  new item or `\end{questions}`.  Possibly by `\fullwidth`.